# Check if fields is not null in PouchDB selectors

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have this query:

```
localDB.find({
            selector: {tablename: 'my_table', 'data.isvisible': true},
            fields: ['_id', 'data']
        }).then(function (result) {..... }
```

How can I insert a condition of existence in the selector? For example, how can I add - as the query condition in selector - that there is a data.name field, so that data.name is not null?

Comment: For future searches! Remember that Couchdb, pouchdb, couchbase, etc, are not relational databases. I dont know if you can add an "as" statement, but the "find" plugin is use the "Cloudant" scheme (check cloudant query: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html)